# Evaluating a written exam without scanning

Tags: r-exams

I am looking for a way to evaluate a multiple choice exam without using the generated **nops format** and scanned answers.

The problem is, that our University has a standard format for written exams and I hence cannot use the generated pdf.

Can I somehow manually create the file needed for the evaluation of the exam with the r-exam package?

Answer (score 0):

R/exams offers various output formats (http://www.R-exams.org/intro/oneforall/) for the same exercises. For example, you can use `exams2pdf()` to create a custom LaTeX-based PDF format or you can use `exams2pandoc()` for Word Docx output. Possibly one of these could be combined with the university's official format?

(P.S.: It is not yet clear to me what the workflow for generating and evaluating an exam in the university's format is for you. Hence I'm not sure how to best combine R/exams with it. If you edit your question I might be able to edit my answer.)